# in log4j2 version 2.17.1 unable to have the current log name suffixed with current date

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2 version 2.17.1 and I am unable to have with this setting in log4j.xml :

```
            <RollingFile name="EVENT_LOG_FILE" fileName="${path}/kpi/${logNamePrefix}_events-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                        filePattern="${path}/kpi/${logNamePrefix}_events-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                </Policies>
                <PatternLayout pattern="TSL=%d{yyyyMMdd:HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'},%m%n" />
            </RollingFile>
```

the current date file named with the current date.

Example for a file generated today : Jul 17th 2023

Current : the filename is incorrectly named with this suffix : 2023-07-07

```
rw-rr-. 1 owner group  12345 Jul  17 08:30 prefix_events-2023-07-07.log
```

Expected : the suffix must be 2023-07-17

```
rw-rr-. 1 owner group  12345 Jul  17 08:30 prefix_events-2023-07-17.log
```

Observation : 2023-07-07 seems to be the name of the oldest file available

P.S. I don't need to have any rolling policy nor any compression happening on my log file if that can help address the issue

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Remove the `fileName` attribute from your configuration and it will work as requested.

The rolling file appender has two [rollover strategies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RolloverStrategy.html):

- the [`DefaultRolloverStrategy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/DefaultRolloverStrategy.html) is useful when the current log file and the archived ones follow a **different** naming convention. To enable it you need to specify both `fileName` and `filePattern`.
- the [`DirectWriteRolloverStrategy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/DirectWriteRolloverStrategy.html) is useful when all the log files follow a common naming convention, which is your case. To enable this strategy you need to omit the `fileName` attribute.

What happens in your case is that you provide both `fileName` and `filePattern`. The `${...}` lookups are resolved at **configuration** time (which happened on July, 7th). After the initial interpolation of your configuration their values are:

- `fileName=".../kpi/prefix_events-2023-07-07.log"`
- `filePattern=".../kpi/prefix_events-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"`

At each rollover the current file `prefix_events-2023-07-07.log` is moved to the file corresponding to the current date.